# Is it a bad practice to use eval() in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I know that using eval() is a bad practice for web development purpose because hackers can use it for cross domain scripting. However is it still a bad practice to use it for mobile app development? If so, why?

Comment: I would not be that lazy to use this, but I don't have any reasonable arguments, so I won't add an answer.

Comment: Is there some reason that you want to use it?  If it is bad for desktop, it is STILL bad for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using eval() during application development can make your life hard. The evaluated code has access to variables in the scope it was evaluated. This'll easily lead to errors in the program when the new code overwrites your vars. And since the eval'ed code is a string, you won't have so easy to debug this problem. Add the security and performance issues (JS parsers try to pre-compile the code for faster execution, which won't happen if a code hidden inside a string) and you will find that you can make your work easier avoiding eval().

Just in case you really, really need to use the code hidden in a string, use the Function() constructor, with the code string as an argument. That way you will at least avoid the variables overwrite problems.

Example of the difference between eval() and Function():

```
(function(){
    var a = 1;
    eval('var a = 2; console.log(a)'); // logs 2
    console.log(a); // also logs 2, the a variable is changed
})();

(function(){
    var b = 1;
    Function('var b = 2; console.log(b)')(); // logs 2
    console.log(b); // logs 1, the code string was executed in it's own scope
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is still bad.

If your app sends data to a server for processing, `eval` could be used maliciously. Also, if your app is a game, eval could be used to cheat by changing internal variables and object containing scores, for example.

Don't forget that running code using `eval` can be relatively slow. Mobile devices are generally slower than 'normal' computers and therefore your app will seem much slower than others if it is used often.

Anyway, are you sure you really need `eval`? There are always better alternatives.